# Couchbase View not returning array value

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am trying to create a view to group on a particular attribute inside an array. However, the below map function is not returning any result.

JSON Document Structure :

```
{
   "jsontype": "survey_response",
   "jsoninstance": "xyz",
   "jsonlanguage": "en_us",
   "jsonuser": "test@test.com",
   "jsoncontact": "test@mayoclinic.com",
   "pages": [
       {
           q-placeholder": "q1-p1",
           q:localized": "q1-localized-p1",
           q-answer-placeholder": "jawaabu121",
           q-answer-localized": "localized jawaabu1"
       },
       {
           q-placeholder": "q2-p2",
           q:localized": "q2-localized-p2",
           q-answer-placeholder": "jawaabu221",
           q-answer-localized": "localized jawaabu2"
       },
       {
           "q-placeholder": "q3-p3",
           "q:localized": "q3-localized-p3",
           "q-answer-placeholder": "jawaabu313",
           "q-answer-localized": "localized jawaabu3"
       }
   ]
}
```

Map Function :

```js
function(doc, meta){
emit(doc.jsoninstance,[doc.pages[0].q-placeholder, doc.pages[0].q-localized,doc.pages[0].q-answer-placeholder,q-answer-localized]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a typo at the end of your emit statement:
`doc.pages[0].q-answer-placeholder,q-answer-localized`.

Instead `q-answer-localized` should be changed to `doc.pages[0].q-answer-localized`.

Further to this it seems that you have defined a field as `q-localized` in your emit statement, but actually according to the sample document that you posted this should actually be `q:localized`, I assume that this was a mistake in the snippet of the document and not the emit statement, but if not then will also need amending.

I would imagine errors like this would be flagged up in the view engine's map-reduce error log, in future you should check this log so that you will be able to debug errors like this yourself.

The location of the `mapreduce_errors` log can be found in the [Couchbase documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-logs.html)